# Android Recyclerview notifyItemChanged(position ,payLoad) don't work if the view at that position is not visible on screen or scrolled out

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using `RecyclerView` in my app, it has `itemViewCache` of 20 items because max possible size of my list would be 20. It is "Single Item  Selection List". Now When the list loads, the first cell becomes highlighted as default selected position. If i click the cell at different position, the view at that position becomes selected & highlighted, simultaneously previously selected view becomes white ie unselected.
Above works fine as I use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(position, payLoad)` method to update data in the list. But when the cell at currently selected  position is scrolled out of the screen and I try to select new position, however the new cell grabs the highlighting and becomes selected, it does not makes previously selected cell white. For the cell at scrolled out position, system dont even call the `notifyDataSetChanged(positioin, payLoad)` method to make ui in it. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I work a lot with `RecyclerViews`.

Here is the code of my adapter :

```
class EventsCalendarAdapter(var eventSectionedFrag: EventSectionedFrag, var arrayList: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.adapter_calendar_months, parent, false)
    return CalendarHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount() = arrayList.size


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>) {
    if (payloads.isNotEmpty()) {
        var bundle = payloads[0] as Bundle
        var isSelected: Boolean? = bundle.getBoolean("selected")
        var setCurrentMonthSelected: Boolean? = bundle.getBoolean("setMonth")


        with(holder) {
            if (isSelected != null) {
                val tvMonth = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_month)
                tvMonth.apply {
                    setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(eventSectionedFrag.activity!!, if (isSelected) R.color.white else R.color.better_than_black))
                    background.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(eventSectionedFrag.activity!!, if (isSelected) android.R.color.holo_red_light else R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC)
                }
            }

            if (setCurrentMonthSelected != null) {
                val view = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.view_current)
                view.visibility = if (setCurrentMonthSelected) {
                    View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    View.INVISIBLE
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val myHolder = holder as CalendarHolder
    myHolder.bindItems(eventSectionedFrag = eventSectionedFrag, month = arrayList[position], position = position)
}

class CalendarHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bindItems(eventSectionedFrag: EventSectionedFrag, month: String, position: Int) {
        val tvMonth = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_month)
        val cardMonth = itemView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.card_month)
        val view = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.view_current)
        view.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        val callbacks = eventSectionedFrag as CalendarCallbacks

        tvMonth.text = month
        view.apply {
            visibility = if (callbacks.getCurrentMonthPosition() == position) {
                View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }
        cardMonth.setOnClickListener {
            callbacks.onMonthSelected(adapterPosition, tvMonth)
        }
    }
}

fun addMonths(arrayList: ArrayList<String>) {
    this.arrayList.clear()
    this.arrayList.addAll(arrayList)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

interface CalendarCallbacks {
    fun onMonthSelected(position: Int, currentSelectedView: TextView)
    fun getCurrentMonthPosition(): Int
}
```

}

and here is how I am invoking the changes from my activity,

```
override fun notifyCalendar(isCurrentYearSelected: Boolean, position: Int) {
    var bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putBoolean("setMonth", isCurrentYearSelected)
    calendarAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position, bundle)
}
```

Comment: show some code is helpful

Comment: Please check the updated question

Comment: Do you have any ItemDecorators?

Comment: there is no data source?

Comment: Please have a look at updated adapter code

Comment: Seems you don't understand base concepts around RecyclerView. It a fragment code, not adapter. That is the adapter class `EventsCalendarAdapter`. Besides that, can you find this method invitation in your code `addItemDecoration`?

Comment: My bad, please check updated code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int position, java.lang.Object payload)` [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object)):

> Adapter should not assume that the payload will always be passed to onBindViewHolder(), e.g. when the view is not attached, the payload will be simply dropped.

So when the cell at currently selected position is scrolled out of the screen, nothing will change because the old selected view is not exist.

You can modify your `arrayList` to store the selected status in it, or add a method to `CalendarCallbacks` which can fetch the current selected position, but you must take care of changing the selected position when needed.

Comment: Ok, you mean if I update the source data set as per selection, on scroll it will load the view as per the updated value?

Comment: Yes, then `onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int)` will be called when scroll back.

Comment: Thanx man, the second solution "Add a method to CalendarCallbacks which can fetch the current selected position" worked for me. For any future devs reading this question, I must mention here that, in such cases you need to handle both notifyItemChanged() and updating the dataset, too get the expected results.

Comment: Great answer! The view holder must be recyclable in order to be able to call adapter function `notifyItemChanged`.  So update your adapter item  data list and in callback check if `binding.recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)` is not null before calling adapter `notifyItemChange` function.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding `ViewHolder` pattern and `notifyItemChanged` method.

`ViewHolder` - object holding the views, when you scroll through your RecyclerView, those objects are re-used to reduce memory and cpu consumption. Their purpose is to display the data set, it's generally unacceptable to hold any data within them.

`notifyItemChanged` - it's purpose is to explicitly update displayed ViewHolders. You have to modify underlying dataset (including array of selected items) before calling this method, so in case of future `onBindViewHolder` (with empty payloads) item is properly displayed.

Comment: I am not getting your point, I have updated the adapter code in my question. Please have a look at updated code in question.